# Vim Fugitive not loading

Tags: git, vimrc

I have recently been trying to separate my neovim config into multiple files. After moving everything involving vim-fugitive and vim-gitgutter into a separate file, git-gutter is not loading and I cant perform any fugitive actions. I imagine this is a problem caused by how I used vim-plug here. Could anyone help me resolve this error?

here is my init.vim:

```
source $HOME/.config/nvim/default.vim
source $HOME/.config/nvim/fugitive.vim

call plug#begin()

Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'
Plug 'mbbill/undotree'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'junegunn/vim-slash'
Plug 'preservim/nerdcommenter'
Plug 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plug 'Shougo/deoplete.nvim', { 'do': 'UpdateRemotePlugins' }
Plug 'zchee/deoplete-jedi'
Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
Plug 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'do': { ->fzf#install() } }
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim' 
Plug 'airblade/vim-rooter'
"Plug 'stsewd/fzf-checkout.vim'

call plug#end()

"Plugin specific configuration

colorscheme gruvbox
set background=dark
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1

let g:fzf_layout = { 'window': {'width': 0.8, 'height': 0.8 }}
let $FZF_DEFAULT_OPS='--reverse'

" plugin key mappings
nmap <leader>c <plug>NERDCommenterToggle<SPACE>
nnoremap <leader>u :UndotreeShow<CR>
nnoremap <leader>pv :wincmd v<bar> :Ex <bar> :vertical resize 30<CR>
nnoremap <leader>ps :Rg<SPACE>

let g:deoplete#enable_at_startup = 1
autocmd InsertLeave,CompleteDone * if pumvisible() == 0 | pclose | endif

" disable autocompletion, cause we use deoplete for completion
let g:jedi#completions_enabled = 0

" open the go-to function in split, not another buffer
let g:jedi#use_splits_not_buffers = "right"4
```

and here is my fugitive.vim

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
call plug#end()

"key mappings for fugitive
nmap <leader>gs :G<CR>
nmap <leader>gj :diffget //3<CR>
nmap <leader>gf :diffget //2<CR>
nnoremap <leader>gc :GCheckout<CR>
```

Comment: Re: multiple files, everything in the plugin directory gets sourced unless you specify `--noplugin`. My own setup places lots of files in `~/.vim/plugin`

Comment: so if I just placed my fugitve.vim file into the plugin folder it will load without me having to say `source fugitive.vim`?

Comment: Yep @destroyer449

Comment: does this work on neovim? I tried this and it did not seem to make it function

Comment: You probably need the right directory: whatever your neovim config dir is + plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using two separate `plug#begin()` blocks for vim-plug and that's not really supported. You should have a single `plug#begin()` and `plug#end()` and all the plug-ins registered inside that block.

You could fix that by using the following inside your `init.vim`:

```
source $HOME/.config/nvim/default.vim

call plug#begin()

source $HOME/.config/nvim/fugitive.vim

Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'
" ...

call plug#end()
```

And then in `fugitive.vim`:

```
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'

"key mappings for fugitive
nmap <leader>gs :G<CR>
nmap <leader>gj :diffget //3<CR>
nmap <leader>gf :diffget //2<CR>
nnoremap <leader>gc :GCheckout<CR>
```

It's fine to add other unrelated configurations such as mappings inside the `plug#begin()` to `plug#end()` block.

(Note 1: You should probably use `nnoremap` for the mappings above, there's really no reason not to use non-recursive mappings, which are generally safer.)

(Note 2: Instead of sourcing separate `*.vim` files from your `init.vim`, consider keeping everything inside `init.vim` and using folding for organization. Fold markers tend to work great on `*.vim` files.)

Comment: I’ve found i dont mind having separate files for some things, but i put them in plugin. YMMV

Comment: @Ben But as far as I can tell, you can't (or shouldn't?) load new plug-ins (as in vim-plug plug-ins) from a `plugin/*.vim` file. I believe that's too late in startup to do that. Perhaps it works, but I don't believe it's actually supported... For instance, if you modify `&rtp` after Vim is finished with the vimrc file, I'm not sure it will correctly load the `plugin/*.vim` files from the new directory you added to `&rtp`...

Comment: Yes, that all seems true. I was referring more generally to note 2, but in that context i agree.